# Memory allocating issues with C + x86 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, memory-management, x86

So I have this C snippet:

```
char* uint_to_binary(unsigned int var, char* buffer);
//...
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    unsigned int var;
    scanf("%d", &var);
    buffer = uint_to_binary(var, buffer);
}
```

Where uint_to_binary is an x86 assembly function:

```
    global uint_to_binary

    section .text

uint_to_binary:
    push    ebp         
    mov     ebp, esp    
    push    ebx         

%define var   [ebp+8]
%define buffer [ebp+12]

    mov     eax, buffer         
    test    eax, eax                    
    jz      fin                 

    mov     edx, var   
    mov     byte [eax], "0"
```

The assembly function is longer of course but I cut it off there cause at the final instruction,

```
mov byte [eax], "0"
```

, I get a segmentation fault. This is resolved by allocating memory to the buffer pointer argument like so:

```
char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

in the main program. This doesn't make much sense to me, because later in the assembly program I overwrite memory positions buffer+1, buffer+2, etc., which haven't been mallocated, without segmentation faults, whereas it's impossible to overwrite a not-mallocated buffer+0 without getting a segfault.

Moreso, in that very same program, I pass not-mallocated void* pointers as arguments to a different assembly function, where I also overwrite those memory positions using the mosvb instruction, and no segmentation faults occur:

```
void* copy_memory_block(void* target, void* source, unsigned int length);
//...
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *target, *source;
    unsigned int length = 5;
    target = copy_memory_block(target,source,length);
}
```

And in the assembly function, I simply store pointers target and source on registers EDI and ESI and overwrite them with a rep movsb instruction. This yields no segmentation faults. So, what's going on with that first segfault that occurs if I don't mallocate a byte for the char pointer?

Comment: Memory protection isn't byte granular, it won't catch all invalid accesses. You should allocate all space you intend to write to. You might want to use `valgrind` to check for violations.

Comment: Before you changed it to use `malloc`, was `buffer` on the stack? `%define buffer [ebp+12]` perhaps the label was visible, but data outside of the function where it is used, is not viable.

Comment: If your code does not segfault, and prints correct result - that's not proof of it being valid. It may still have bugs, just no bug did manifest during that "valid" run. If you want "safer" environment looking after your bugs, try C# or Java, or other "managed" languages, where the memory protection is stronger (for the price of considerably lower performance).

Comment: @Jester That makes sense - I suppose if memory protection _could_ stop me from overwriting non-mallocated memory, it _would_

Comment: @WeatherVane I considered stack shenanigans but it's not that - debugger shows the memory address "buffer" that's passed to the function is the one that ends up on EAX

Comment: @Ped7g You're completely right, and that's why I made this question: to further understand memory allocation on C and not write _invalid_ code that _works_. This was all done for learning purposes - I'm not releasing this to the public or anything

Comment: It was more like warning, that in non-managed environment the mere fact something looks like it "works" doesn't mean much (but then again, in managed languages there are still runtime bugs going without exceptions, so it doesn't help *that* much). While you have some bug/undefined behaviour, you have only so-much-chance to trigger the crash handler. You can easily overwrite "your" memory allocated for other variables, one of the worst bugs to track down, as the code will seemingly "randomly" do something unexpected, and when debugging the value will never change while looking into that part ;)